# How to change the WordPress admin interface to my own interface style?

Tags: wordpress, interface, customization

I would like to use my own CMS interface style on WordPress, is there a way to change WordPress interface?

I found that Custom Login and some other plugins are used to modify WordPress interface, but it is very restricted. Is there a way to change the WordPress interface completely to your own style?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no option to change the admin panel completely. You can always play a bit with CSS using [wp_admin_css_color()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_admin_css_color/) function to register your own admin styles.